# Как передать как аргумент значение одного из классов полученных через querySelectorAll в функцию с целью открытия конкретного попапа?

Tags: javascript

```
            <section class="profile">
                <div class="profile__user">
                    <img src="./images/Avatar.jpg" alt="Фотография вашего профиля" class="profile__avatar">
                    <div class="profile__info">
                        <h1 class="profile__user-name"></h1>
                        <button type="button" class="profile__edit-button"></button>
                        <p class="profile__user-job"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="profile__add-button"></button>
            </section>
       <!--Попап элементы-->
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="popup__container">
                <button type="button" class="popup__close"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="popup__container">
                <button type="button" class="popup__close"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
const popupOpen = document.querySelectorAll(".popup");
const profileFormButton = document.querySelector(".profile__edit-button");
const newPlaceFormButton = document.querySelector(".profile__add-button");
profileFormButton.addEventListener("click", openForm(popupOpen[0]));
newPlaceFormButton.addEventListener("click", openForm(popupOpen[1]));

function openForm() {
  popupOpen.classList.add("popup_opened");
}
```

Comment: если попапы все одинаковые, может стоит через js отрисовывать один ?

Comment: А по какому принципу вы собираетесь выбирать попап?

Comment: Попапы будут содержать разные формы (для профиля и для добавления новой карточки на сайте); попап буду выбирать через индекс после добавления их всех через querySelectorAll(“.popup”)